# Use appsettings.custom.json to overwrite appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

I have an ASP.NET Core API that reads in config from a appsettings.json file. This is ran as a Windows service and can be installed/uninstalled. This means that updating will overwrite the appsettings.json file. To solve this, I want to be able to create a appsettings.custom.json, that contains only the settings from appsettings.json that I want a different value for. So basically this appsettings.custom.json file should overrule the settings from appsettings.json. I've been playing around, but the settings that are used are always from appsettings.json, it basically ignores the appsettings.custom.json.

```
        private const string CustomAppSettingsJson = "appsettings.custom.json";
        private const string DefaultAppSettingsJson = "appsettings.json";

 Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(DefaultAppSettingsJson, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile(CustomAppSettingsJson, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
```

Is something like this possible? Can I make some sort of hierarchic order in the files?

I tried switching the order of the adding of the json files, but without success.

Comment: I noticed that the files are correctly read in in program.cs in the CreateHostBuilder method, but the configuration injected in startup.cs does not contain the appsettings.custom.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the files were not added to the configuration used in startup that registers the options classes.

I used to read in the config files in the Main method in program.cs:

```
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(DefaultAppSettingsJson, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(CustomAppSettingsJson, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```

This configuration however is not passed to the startup.cs and therefor not injected in my dependencies. The appsettings.json file by default was added to the configuration in the application, which caused the confusion on my side.

Adding the following piece of code to the CreateHostBuilder method in program.cs made sure the config created in program.cs was added to the rest of the application:

```
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile(DefaultAppSettingsJson, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile(CustomAppSettingsJson, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
```

Comment: please add some code or sample

Answer (score 1):

The last provider takes precedence so you'll need to swap the ordering.

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(DefaultAppSettingsJson, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)                
                .AddJsonFile(CustomAppSettingsJson, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build()
```

https://youtu.be/sBQlIcdLM0s

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the YT video (18:50) you mention the exact opposite, "the last one wins". I tried it both ways, both give the same result, always the default appsettings.json config value

Comment: I got it fixed, and your comment is wrong, it is the other way around, as you say in the video. The last file you add takes precedence.

Comment: Sorry yeah, that's correct I'll update answer